# Цикличное выполнение определённой функции .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, mvc

Всем привет. Мне необходимо получать данные с определённого источника и передавать их в клиент.
Сейчас при каждом запросе я получаю данные и передаю их клиенту, но в случае если посетителей будет очень много, следствием будет и очень много лишних запросов к ресурсу.
Я хочу получать данные в определённом промежутке времени и добавлять их в базу. Как это возможно сделать?

Comment: Использовать таймер?

Comment: Да, остановился на нём.

Answer (score 1):

Решением стали таймеры.

```
TimerCallback timeCB = new TimerCallback(GetInfoForUsers);
Timer time = new Timer(timeCB, null, 0, 1000);
```

Ранее у меня были проблемы с их запуском, т.к. требовалось дополнительно передавать в функцию и контекст контроллеров, что бы пользоваться их функциями. Сейчас я решил реализовать его прямо в контроллере, и запускать этот таймер во время запроса с админ панели.